# What distribution does the number of inversions of an array of n distinct numbers follow

Tags: probability-distributions

An array of n distinct numbers. I want to know what distribution its [number of inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) follows.

I used Mathematica to simulate and initially felt that it obeyed normal distribution:

```
<< Combinatorica`
data = Table[Inversions@RandomSample[Range[10], 10], 10000];
ListPlot[BinCounts[data, {0, 50, 1}]]
```

[image]

But it's not a strict mathematical proof. I want to know a strict mathematical proof of its distribution.

[Here](https://www.zhihu.com/question/414501909?utm_source=qzone&utm_medium=social&utm_oi=996498487571230720) is a similar post. The reference book used in this post is *Combinatorics of permutations* by Miklos Bona.

```
ListPlot /@ 
 Table[CoefficientList[Series[QFactorial[n, q], {q, 0, n (n - 1)/2}], 
   q], {n, 9}] (*http://oeis.org/A008302*)
```

Comment: The GF is $$\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{X^k-1}{X-1}$$

Comment: @AnginaSeng Thank you very much. Can you write down the answer in detail?

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A008302 for tabulation, discussion, and many links to the literature

Comment: Have you followed up on my suggestion, Please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you very much for your guidance. I am reading the content of this post.